# Tile based javascript game - laggy scroll

Tags: javascript

I am creating a tile based game in javascript. I am absolutely beginner.
The plan is to learn javascript while I trying to make this game. I am having serious lagging issues when I am trying to scroll the "game"

For a live preview you can see here whats bad:
http://iwansfactory.com/tycoon/index.html

My javascript generates them and they HTML part looks like this:
`<div class="tiletype100" id="x0y0" style="left: 2151px; top: -540px;"></div>`

The css:

```
.tiletype2 {
  z-index: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 600px;
  height: 800px;
  background-image: url("http://iwansfactory.com/tycoon/road2.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

The javascript scroll function is this:

```
var right = document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
var bottom = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
var rightscrollvalue = 0;
var bottomscrollvalue = 0;

function rightenter() {
  rightscrollvalue = 40;
  scrollright();
}

function leftenter() {
  rightscrollvalue = -40;
  scrollright();
}

function rightout() {
  rightscrollvalue = 0;
}

function scrollright() {
  if (rightscrollvalue != 0) {
    right = right + rightscrollvalue;
    console.log(right);
    window.scrollTo(right, bottom);
    setTimeout(function() {
      scrollright();
    }, 50);
  }
}

function bottomenter() {
  bottomscrollvalue = 40;
  scrollbottom();
}

function topenter() {
  bottomscrollvalue = -40;
  scrollbottom();
}

function bottomout() {
  bottomscrollvalue = 0;
}

function scrollbottom() {
  if (bottomscrollvalue != 0) {
    bottom = bottom + bottomscrollvalue;
    console.log(bottom);
    window.scrollTo(right, bottom);
    setTimeout(function() {
      scrollbottom();
    }, 50);
  }
}
```

Comment: Every time you hit `scrollbottom()` or `scrollright()` you start an endless loop where the same function is called again 50 ms later. What was your intention when you added the `setTimeout` calls?

Comment: Why do you use a timeout of 50 in scroll functions?

Comment: Try to use `requestAnimationFrame(function() {scrollbottom(););` instead of `setTimeout(function() {scrollbottom();}, 50); and at all other places where you update the view like scrollright etc...

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I stop the loop by setting
bottomscrollvalue = 0;
and here is a check in the function for that
if (bottomscrollvalue != 0) {

Comment: How would this code look like with requestAnimationFrame - sorry for beginner question :S

function scrollbottom() {
  if (bottomscrollvalue != 0) {
    bottom = bottom + bottomscrollvalue;
    console.log(bottom);
    window.scrollTo(right, bottom);
    setTimeout(function() {
      scrollbottom();
    }, 50);
  }
}

Comment: requestAnimationFrame() is the proper way of refreshing the DOM regardless of at what frequency your display driver works It collects this refresh info from the hardware and does all DOM updates at once at proper time. As I have said you just need to replace the  `setTimeout(function() { scrollbottom(); }, 50);` part with `requestAnimationFrame(function() {scrollbottom()};);`

Comment: Thanks for update Redu. This works but still laggy
requestAnimationFrame(function() {scrollbottom();});

Comment: If I remove the tiles css then it works really well with the requestAnimationFrame.

Comment: Try to decrease the rightscrollvalue and bottomscrollvalue to 10 or 5 and try again. And it seems that your tiles are huge (800x600px). Hardware tries to scale them. Try to use tiles at the correct sizes as they get displayed on the screen.

Comment: I have many different tiles, they all look similar to this in css:

    .tiletype100 {
      z-index: 200;
      position: absolute;
      width: 600px;
      height: 800px;
      background-image: url("http://iwansfactory.com/tycoon/grass0.png");
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }

Comment: I used the big tiles as some elements are tall and has a long shadows
I will separate them from flatter tiles so I can use much smaller for most. Thanks for your help Reda!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your design uses large overlapping tiles that are mostly transparent. This requires a lot of CPU power for rendering, thus making the game laggy.

I propose you make your tiles smaller, just as large as they have to be (so there is a non-transparent pixel on every edge of the image) and use offsets for larger tiles so they get rendered at the right position.